# Plesk Updates Overwriting my PHP.ini

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, php, automatic-updates

This may be more relevant on stackoverflow, if so please migrate it :-)

I have had to disable automatic updates in Plesk on my Windows server as everytime an update is installed, my php.ini configurations get wiped and I have to re-configure PHP.

I know it is not meant to do this as it does not do it on my Linux server. Has anybody else had this issue? Is there an easy fix?

Thanks in advance

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about [`working with a service provider's management interface, such as cPanel`](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just take a "Service Plan" you used for your 50 domains and setup required PHP settings there. All 50 domains will be reconfigured then. If you didn't create your own plans, it is likely that "Default" or "Default Unlimited" plan was used. This information should be shown in Plesk anyway, so find the plan name and edit the plan settings.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, this is in fact what I have done. After managing to sync my php settings throughout each subscription and each subdomain, everything was working fine. The only thing that is not working is loading extensions using the additional parameters text box. I think this is a bug though

Answer (score 0):

I have realised the root of problem. Plesk does not support the editing of the PHP.ini, the way to edit the PHP settings is by manually entering the settings in the domain control panel. This is hugely irritating as I have over 50 domains and they all need to same PHP settings.

Hopefully I will just be able to apply a skeleton setting to all the domains